# What are these Moebius-esque strips called?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a ring-like shape with two broad faces... We cut the ring and make a twist of 180 degrees to produce the world famous Moebius strip. A one-faced shape.

Let's say we cut the shape again and make an infinite series of 180 degrees twists... This would produce a consecutive series of one and two faced shapes... Do these shapes, particularly the one faced shapes, receive any special study in topology? Where can I find info on these?

Thanks!

Comment: Topologically each of those one-faced shapes is again a Moebius strip, just with a different embedding in R^3.

Comment: And the two-faced ones are just cylinders, again with different embeddings in $\mathbb R^3$.